# Plugin dropping pagination variable

Tags: plugins, pagination

I'm having problem with a plugin. In the plugin, I noticed the url string switches after the page load and the '&paged=#' disappears. For example:

On page load: http://www.domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=app-commission-junction&tab=stores_relations&paged=2

After page load: http://www.domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=app-commission-junction&tab=stores_relations

I've tried it on multiple browsers and had the same problem. I've cleared cache but it did not help.

Here's the code:

```
private function stores_pagination() {
    $args = $this->pagination_args();
    $current_url = remove_query_arg( array( 'paged' ), scbUtil::get_current_url() );

    $pagination = paginate_links( array(
        'base' => $current_url . '%_%',
        'format' => '&paged=%#%',
        'show_all' => true,
        'prev_next' => false,
        'total' => $args['total_pages'],
        'current' => $args['current_page'],
    ) );

    echo html( 'div', array( 'class' => 'tablenav storesnav' ),
        html( 'div', array( 'class' => 'tablenav-pages' ), $pagination )
    );
}


private function pagination_args() {
    $args['per_page'] = 50;
    $args['current_page'] = ( isset( $_GET['paged'] ) ) ? (int) $_GET['paged'] : 1;
    $args['end_results'] = $args['per_page'] * $args['current_page'];
    $args['start_results'] = $args['end_results'] - $args['per_page'];
    $args['total_results'] = count( $this->get_cj_stores() );
    $args['total_pages'] = ceil( $args['total_results'] / $args['per_page'] );

    return $args;
}
```

Does anyone see a problem with the code?

Comment: do you have more than 50 posts?  Looks like code will set 50 posts per page.

Comment: Yes I have more than 50.  It is a custom post type and there are several hundred.  Around 8 pages are created.